# How to install MK - a program "Holy Bible"

Tags: software-installation, scripts, 18.04

I am a fresh user of Ubuntu. I enjoy with 18.04 version and there are many things to learn. As for example to launch a program called "Holy Bible." The distributor is the "Institute for Bible Translation" - https://ibtrussia.org/en/pc.

The installation of the package comes along with the file that provides the script to launch the program; but I couldn't as a result of my incompetence.

Here it is the script:

```
#!/bin/bash
cd "$( dirname "${BASH_SOURCE[0]}" )"
"./MK/xulrunner/xulrunner" --app "./MK/xulsword/application.ini" -profile "./MK/profile"
```

Would you please explain how to run the program with this script from "Terminal"

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

Let’s say you extracted the archive to `~/Downloads/Holy_Bible`, then open a terminal with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> and execute:

```
~/Downloads/Holy_Bible/start-MK.sh
```

You can also try to just click on the `start-MK.sh` file in your file manager, at least PCManFM asks what to do and lets you choose to “Execute” the file, which runs the program.

Protip: To change the program’s language, just press <kbd>F1</kbd> and select a language in the appearing dropdown menu.

Comment: Excellent solution. The program was executed through the Terminal. I set up a language. On the left panel there appeared icon MK that associated with Holy Bible. However, when I closed the application with a purpose to start it again, I found no more the icon titled MK. Now I don't know how to open the program I've just installed. I am so thankful for giving me the instruction how to run the program. Now would you please help me again with finding the icon to start "Holy Bible".

Comment: @Little I‘d [create a launcher](https://askubuntu.com/q/64222/507051) for it, its command (or `Exec` line respectively) would be `~/Downloads/Holy_Bible/start-MK.sh` in my example.